# MUI grid dynamic squares

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI grid component. I need the child grid items to increase in size with the viewport, but to also maintain the square dimensions.

Reproducible example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-grid-demo-forked-6ws4yj?file=/src/index.js

Grid component:

```
    <Box sx={{ width: { xs: "100%", lg: "80%", xl: "100%" } }}>
      <Grid
        container
        columns={{ xs: 2, lg: 2, xl: 4 }}
        rowSpacing={{ xs: 1, xl: 2 }}
        columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, xl: 2 }}
      >
        {tiles.map((tile) => (
          <Grid item key={tile} xs={1} lg={1} xl={1}>
            <Box
              sx={{
                width: {
                  xs: "calc(100% - 4px)",
                  lg: "calc(100% - 4px)",
                  xl: "100%"
                },
                height: { xs: "139.5px", lg: "164px", xl: "198px" },
                border: "1px solid black",
                borderRadius: 2,
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                cursor: "pointer"
              }}
            >
              test
            </Box>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Box>
```

How can I have the height change dynamically with the width to keep the square ratio?

Comment: try giving it a `height: auto;` and a `aspect-ratio: 1;` (or whatever aspect-ratio you need)

Comment: @Boguz no luck :(

Comment: @Boguz - update, it worked with aspectRatio: '1/1'; Thanks!